# python selenium check if element is clickable x times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to try click on element x times, if element is not clickable then wait x seconds and try again. I think this should be simple, but I am not able to make it work for me, it is executed once only. What is wrong with my code? Thanks for all suggestions!

```
button_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'elementtxt')]") 
for z in range(3):
  try:
    button_element.click()
    break
  except Exception as e:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` breaks out of the loop. remove the `break` and the loop should continue.

```
for z in range(3):
  try:
    button_element.click()
    ## no break
  except Exception as e:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
```

note that with `break` removed the code will still not do what i think you want it to do.

this code will *try* to click three times. it might click successfully or it might throw exception. doesn't matter. it will try to click three times and done.

if you want to *successfully* click three times you need one loop which tries to click untill successful and another loop which repeates the process three times.

something like this:

```
for z in range(3):
  while true:
    try:
      button_element.click()
      break    ## <---- this will break out of the while loop
    except Exception as e:
      time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
```

here the `while` loop will try to click until successful. and then the `for` loop will repeat this three times. so in the end you have three successful clicks and only god knows how many tries (you can count the failed attempts by incrementing a variable in the `except`).